# Product Catalog not updating but Search catalog is

Tags: magento2, catalog, catalogsearch, magento-2.1.7, ultimo

Magento Version: 2.1.7 EE
Theme: Ultimo Theme - Infortis.

I'm using the theme config settings to update the Catalog view page but no matter what i do it doesn't even seem to update the view, even after clearing cache/indexing etc.

However i have noticed it does update the catalog search view, so the settings are working it's just not taking effect on the catalog page.

The theme support don't seem to have any idea why it's not working as it should, has anyone got any ideas what i can do/check?

Comment: have you clear cache and done reindex for the same ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try enabling the template hints to see which file is being loaded

```
bin/magento dev:template-hints:enable
```

Comment: Just did that, figured out a plugin catalog page was being loaded over the theme one, cheers!

Comment: Could up upvote, please? @AdamGlover

Comment: I did, but don't have enough rep for it to display publicly as it's a new account sorry!